# angular2 bootstrap dynamic carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamic images coming from a `json` and doing `*ngFor` to loop through the objs and putting it in a carousel using bootstrap carousel, but I want to put a readmore link within the `*ngFor` so each item will have a read more.

I can't figure out how to do when a user click "readmore" it will scroll to its relative item showing about the image if that makes sense.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let journey of Journey">
  <div class="journey_block">
    <div class="icon-workflow">
        <div class="view view-fourth">
        <img src="{{ journey.imageName }}" alt="">
        <div class="mask">
            <a href="" class="info" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0">Read More</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <h4 class="journey_title">
        <a [href]="journey.journey_url" *ngIf="journey.journey_url != 'javascript:;' " class="float-shadow">
            {{journey.title}}
        </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

My attempt is I thought I would then need to do for loop, I have 5 items in total in the json data.

```
getImg() {
   this.http.get('./journey.json')
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        if(data) {
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            this.Journey = jsonObj.journey;

            for (var i = 0; i <  this.Journey.length; i++) {
                var element =  this.Journey[i];
                this.objCount = element;
                console.log(this.objCount);
            }
        }

    });
};
```

View full html structure of the carousel

[Carousel structure](https://plnkr.co/edit/qTgvzUYCGzFqqpeRZv8K?p=catalogue)

Comment: edit `data-slide-to="0"` into `data-slide-to="{{index}}"`. Or something similar.

Comment: Yeah, but wondering if I have to do a loop like what I'm doing in the code just to achieve what I'm trying to do. Because I put {{objCount}} in the slide-to ="" and its giving me an error.

Comment: Yes, just `data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="{{i}}"` is enough to make a carousel slide to the given index slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the index inside of the loop for making the `data-slide-to` attribute unique. This could be done by the predefined Angular2 value `index`.

**Example**

```
<!-- Angular 2.0 -->
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    {{i}} {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**In your code:**

```
<div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let journey of Journey; let i = index">
    <div class="journey_block">
      <div class="icon-workflow">
          <div class="view view-fourth">
          <img src="{{ journey.imageName }}" alt="">
          <div class="mask">
              <a href="" class="info" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" [attr.data-slide-to]="i">Read More</a>
          </div>
          </div>
          <h4 class="journey_title">
          <a [href]="journey.journey_url" *ngIf="journey.journey_url != 'javascript:;' " class="float-shadow">
              {{journey.title}}
          </a>
          </h4>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this is what I get when I put {{i}} in the data-slide. Can't bind to 'slide-to' since it isn't a known native property

Comment: Is the {{ i }} possible to start from -1? I'm doing two separate *ngFor one is for the images to be in col-sm-4 and the other one is to use the full carousel screen. So when I click read more the items are not relative to each other.

Comment: Not that familiar with Angular2, try `ngFor="let journey of Journey; let i = index - 1"` or `[attr.data-slide-to]="i-1"`

Comment: Please see the carousel structure.

Comment: Yeah I thought that way too but I think that's not the way ehe.